# detecting timeseries anomalies with python

Tags: python, time-series, detection, anomaly-detection

I am studying a large collection of time series.
In general, the time series follow a linear trend (with some noise), an example looks like this:

[image: Example of normal time series]

Sometimes, however, there is a fault in the detector, which causes a sudden drop in the y-values of the time series. Example:

[image]

**My question: How can I detect such 'jumps' using Python?**

Comment: Have a look at http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/basic_gp.ipynb .  The technology involved there can be used to create a simple machine-learning black box into which you can feed an arbitrary long beginning of a time series and ask it for its short-term prediction.  If all the following actual values have a clear trend to be below (or above) the predicted values, then you can report on this situation.  I'm using this in a similar (and even simpler) scenario just like this.

Answer (score 0):

Default anomaly detection strategies involve predicting a time series at a given point and compare it to new real values. If there is a difference you have an anomaly.

In your example your timeseries model would be a linear funciton. E.g. at July 2012 you would forecast the next five data points. Then you compare the new points when they are measured. If you have a drop in your data like in your bottom image the residuals would be higher than expected.

For you residuals you could assume a gaussian distribution. If the calculted residual is more than e.g.2 sigma away you could flag it.